# RDS Multi-AZ bottlenecking write performance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are using an RDS MySQL 5.6 instance (db.m3.2xlarge) on sa-east-1 region and during write intensive operations we are seeing (on CloudWatch) that both our Write Throughput and the Network Transmit Throughput are capped at 60MB/s.

We suspected that the Multi-AZ could be responsible for this behaviour and turned it off for testing purposes. We did the same operation and noticed now that the Write Througput wasn't capped anymore and the Network Transmit Throughput was actually zero. This reinforced the idea that this network traffic is between the primary instance and the failover instance on the Multi-AZ setup.

Here is the Cloudwatch chart showing the operation without Multi-AZ and right after the same one with Multi-AZ enabled:

[image: RDS Multi-AZ bottlenecking write performance]

We tried upgrading the instance to one with the highest network performance and also provisioned IOPs but there was no change, when Multi-AZ is on we are always capped at 60MB/s for write.

It's our understanding that Multi-AZ uses synchronous data replication but we can't find any information on the bandwidth limits for the link thru which this replication occurs. Does anyone know anything about it and how to avoid this limits? Or should we live with it?

Comment: DId you mean to post two graphs?

Comment: @JohnHanley, it's only one. In this graph at 17:00 I started the operation without Multi-AZ, after it finished around 18:00 I disabled the Multi-AZ and did the same operation again. If you look closely, you can see that the lines of the chart are close together.

Comment: What is the specific instance type?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot db.m3.2xlarge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never got an ACTUAL explanation from anywhere, but after tons of tests it seems that the m3.2x.large is actually "bugged". I wrote a detailed explanation in my [blog](https://medium.com/meus-pedidos/write-spikes-wars-episode-i-the-aws-rds-m3-2x-large-menace-9cd2802d98aa).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you're seeing a limitation of the replication service *per se*, but it appears that your replication bandwidth shares the same transport as the EBS volume on your instance, thus it's a limitation of the Ethernet bandwidth available to your instance itself (remembering that EBS is network-attached storage).

The network connection on an m3.2xlarge is 1000 Mbit/s, which is equivalent to 125 MiB/s.

Divide that number by two and you get ~60 MB/s for writing to the local instance's EBS volume and another ~60 MB/s for writing to the synchronous replica.

Unfortunately, the implementation details of Multi-AZ replication are not something AWS has publicly explained in enough detail to say conclusively that this is indeed the explanation, but the numbers are suspiciously close to what would be predicted if it is correct.

The m3 family and m4 family of instances have similar specs but also (apparently) some fundamental design differences, so it might be informative to see if the same behavior is true of the m4.2xlarge.

Comment: Interesting point, I forgot to consider the local network usage and considered only the outgoing network usage for replication/EBS, your math totally makes sense. I'll do some more tests and post the results in here.

Comment: I did some new tests and indeed it was a bottleneck in the EBS bandwidth as explained in this doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html

db.m4.4xlarge achieved 133M of WriteThroughput/NetworkTransmit, respecting the spec of 2,000 Mbps (133 * 8 * 2 = 2128 Mbps) EBS Bandwidth.

Comment: @IsraelFonseca perfect.  Well, almost.  I like it when the numbers line up, but a also vigilant against having my hypotheses confirmed by coincidence.  Just to verify, without Multi-AZ enabled, you are also able to push the m4.4xlarge higher... is that correct?

Comment: I didn't disable Multi-AZ on the m4.4xlarge for testing. I did it only in the m3.2xlarge. But I think it's safe to assume that without the Multi-AZ you don't get performance cut, as happened with the m3.2xlarge.

Comment: I did some more tests, and things got stranger. More details in the AWS topic about: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=268107 it seems, that the m3.2xlarge doesn't respect it specs, but m3.xlarge and m4.2xlarge does.

Comment: The m4 is EBS-optimized, while the m3 may or may not be.  This may have a bearing on the bandwidth available to multi-AZ.

Comment: But the docs say it is optimized: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html.

Comment: You're correct.  I had looked for confirmation of that, before, and didn't find it.  I am currently at AWS re:Invent, so I'll try to find an opportunity to bring this up with someone, here, and see if I can learn anything more about any of the lower-level details and their impacts.

Comment: I'll definitely appreciate that. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the same issue, after activating Multi AZ the Write Latency increased dramatically:

[image]

(The instance type is m4.4xlarge)

The reason looks to be the synchronous synchronization process, each write action has to wait until both DBs are responding positively to the modification.

Looks like there is not solution and it is an expected behaviour:

> DB instances using Multi-AZ deployments may have increased write and
>   commit latency compared to a Single-AZ deployment, due to the
>   synchronous data replication that occurs

– [from AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html)

Here is an interesting Redis thread regarding to this:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/61ewvp/rds_multiaz_slow_insert/

the only recommendation I see is *moving to Aurora* :/

Comment: Your latency is much higher than mine on a m4.2xlarge (almost never above 1ms) even with Multi-AZ enabled. Thats seem too high.